# Find key of value within array in hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash categories as following:

```
categories = {"horeca" => ["bar", "waiter", "kitchen"], 
              "retail" => ["eerste", "tweede"]}
```

I want to find they key if the value is included in the array of values.

Something like following

```
categories.key("bar")
```

which would return "horeca"

as of now I can only get "horeca" if I do

```
categories.key(["bar", "waiter", "kitchen"])
```

Comment: I've never programmed in Ruby, but would it be possible to  create a second hash map where you insert (bar, horeca), (waiter, horeca)... and so forth, reversing the values and keys that you have in this map? Then you could easily perform the query you wish.

Comment: Do you want to return the first key with value-array containing 'bar' or all keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try **[`Enumberable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find)**:

```
categories.find { |key, values|
  values.include?("bar")
}.first
```

Comment: `find` called on a hash returns a `[key, value]` pair. To get the key, `first` needs to be called.

Answer (score 5):

As Máté mentioned, you can use `find` if you want to find the first matching element. Use `select` if you want all matching elements. To just get the keys you would do:

```
categories.select { |key, values| values.include?("bar") }.map(&:first)
```

See https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

Comment: instead of `map(&:first)` you can use `keys`.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work, since you are not returned a hash, but a 2 dimensional array like so: `[["first", ["bar", "baz"]], ["second", ["not bar", "baz"]]`

Answer (score 3):

Creating intermediate array and then calling first on it is all unnecessary, also if the hash is large and you want first matched value, following solution is better

```
categories.each{ |k,v| break k if v.include?('bar') }
#=> "horeca"
```

Answer (score 3):

Md. Farhan Memon's solution is generally the preferable solution but it has one downside: If there's no match in the collection, it returns the collection itself – which probably isn't a desirable result. You can fix this with a simple adjustment that combines both `detect/find` and `break`:

```
categories.detect { |key, values| break key if values.include?('bar') }
```

This breaks and returns the value if it finds it and otherwise returns `nil` (which I assume to be the preferable behavior).

If your collection may also contain `nil` values and/or non-arrays, you can improve it further:

```
categories.detect { |key, values| break key if Array(values).include?('bar') }
```

The only downside of this general approach is that it's not particularly intuitive to newcomers: You have to know a bit more than just basic Ruby to understand what's going on without running the code first.